# Using a Stamp from an RSVP Card

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law

Many invitations come with return card envelopes that are already affixed with proper postage. Suppose, the recipient of such a card has no intention of replying (or decides to reply by some other means). Is s/he then allowed to use that unused postage for other purposes?

Why or why not?

Comment: Why not? If someone gives you a bottle of wine to use for your Wednesday night dinner and you don't, aren't you allowed to use that bottle on Shabbas?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Are you? Was the bottle a gift of thanks for inviting you to Wednesday night dinner, or was it for use at the Wednesday night dinner?

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Hmm... Are you? And perhaps this case is slightly different - the stamp isn't actually a gift.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Also, possibly related: [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5780/128)

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman Actually, from the strict letter of the law, you're allowed to use a bottle for Shabbas on a weekday (according to Shulchan Aruch HaRav [Orach Chayim 242:8](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/default.aspx?furl=/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/242/8))

Comment: What would you do with the stamp otherwise? Send it back to them? Toss it?

Comment: Call up the people who sent the invitation and ask them - (and let us know what they say!)

Answer (score 2):

This question is most likely based on the [story of the Chafetz Chaim](http://www.revach.net/halacha/tshuvos/Rav-Menashe-Klein-On-Reusing-Stamps-And-The-Chofetz-Chaim-Ripping-Up-A-Stamp/1849). Rabbi Menashe Klein Zatzal says Al Pi Halacha a stamp may not be reused because the law requires you to pay a fee if you send your letter through the postal system.

However in this case where the stamp was never used as the letter was not sent I do not see why there would be any question, and it would seem to me that there is no problem using it.

Comment: No. I'm actually asking from the angle of the person giving it for a purpose -- and you're using it for a different purpose. Obviously, the case is where the stamp wasn't used... Do you have a source for the premise that you can use it however you wish?

Comment: Then perhaps change your question to indicate that this is what you are asking.

Comment: It already does: I specifically note that I'm referring to "unused" postage.

Comment: @yydl If that's the angle you are asking from, you should include that detail in the question itself. (What we call around here 'motivation'.)

Answer (score 2):

From the "Halacha for Today" on [Thursday, November 15, 2012](http://halachafortoday.com/archives-2/hashovas-aveidah/) (emphasis mine):

> If one receives a letter or an invitation that includes a return envelope with postage already affixed to it there is no obligation to respond to the letter or invitation just because the postage was pre-affixed, and there is also no obligation to return the stamped envelope to the sender
>
> **However, it is prohibited to use the stamped envelope for another purpose; it should be put aside until the arrival of Eliyahu Hanavi.** (Ruling of HaRav Nisim Karelitz Shlita quoted in Sefer Hashovas Aveida K’Halacha[1] page 116)

[1]. By R' Feinhandler. [Read first 40 pages](http://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?23265&lang=eng) for free. [Find in a library](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/45641778) near you. Not available on <hebrewbooks.org>.

Comment: 1) If you know who the sender is, what is the purpose of saving it until Eliyahu HaNavi comes? 2) Since it can be assumed that most people do not have unused-stampted-envelope collections, and simply discard those they do not use, shouldn't there be a presumption that the senders of such envelopes relinquish any expectation of getting them back?

Comment: I'm also confused about how Eliyahu is going to help this.

Comment: @DoubleAA you're joking?

Comment: @Yehoshua No. How would he help? If he means to not get hanaa from it ever, say to bury it. If he means it's really the original sender's, then give it back. What safek is Eliyahu going to mevarer?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm assuming he means if someone would be allowed to use it for his own purposes (from the ending statement he seems to be machmir only mitzad sofek.)

Comment: @Yehoshua So you mean "wait for Eliyahu" == "I don't know"?

Comment: @DoubleAA Listen I'm assuming that was his kavana that the psak given that it's prohibited is only l'chumrah...But like anything said by today's Gedolim be careful how far to take it...Especially since not one savarah or mareh makom was given...

Comment: @DoubleAA the lashon of "until the arrival of Eliyahu Hanavi" is used in SA Choshen Mishpat at times (for example) when in regards to an aveidah the halacha is unclear on what to do. See for example what I saw tonight in Siman 262 Sif 4. Although I agree in this case it seems a bit funny to use this lashon or directive rather.

Comment: @Yehoshua It's also used in the Mishna [BM 3:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%91%D7%90_%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%90_%D7%92_%D7%93) but there it is about identifying an unknown _metzius_ not an unknown _halacha_.